# How can I group a List<Object> into another List<Object> by some attributes

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to group a `List<Object>` which contains

```
Exercice, type, User, passed, ..
```

There are more but those are the most important, the thing is that I'm getting a long list, so I want to group it by :

```
Type, User, NumberOfPassed, NumberOfFaileds
```

For instance I have :

```
Exercice1, hand, Hans@gmail.com, true
Exercice2, hand, Hans@gmail.com, false
Exercice3, hand, Hans@gmail.com, false
Exercice4, hand, Hans@gmail.com, false
Exercice2, hand, Thiago@gmail.com, true
Exercice1, hand, Thiago@gmail.com, true
```

And the output should be

```
Hand, Hans@gmail.com, 1/4
Hand, Thiago@gmail.com, 2/2
```

Comment: Wich values can have type? Only hand or any other value?

Comment: Type is a String, like Hand foot, whatever

Comment: pls, specify your problem in java or kotlin code, don't use both tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could create this object to help you to solve this:

```
public class Result {
  private String type;
  private String email;
  private int numPassed;
  private Double total;

  public Result(String type, String email, boolean approved) {
      total = 1.0;
      this.type = type;
      this.email = email;
      this.numPassed = approved ? 1 : 0;
  }

  public void increase(boolean examResult){
      total++;
      if(examResult){
          numPassed++;
      }
  }

  public boolean isApproved(){
      return numPassed >= total / 2d;
  }

  public String getFraction(){
    return numPassed + "/" + total.intValue();
  }
}
```

And the algorithm to aggroup your list should be like this:

```
private static List<Result> group(List<Input> yourList) {
    List<Result> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Input i : yourList) {
        String type = i.getType();
        String email = i.getEmail();
        boolean approved = i.isApproved();
        Result r = getIfExists(result, type, email);

        if(r != null){
            result.remove(r);
            r.increase(approved);
        } else{
            r = new Result(type, email, approved);
        }

        result.add(r);
    }

    return result;
}

private static Result getIfExists(List<Result> results, String type, String email) {
    Result result = null;
    boolean exit = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size() && !exit; i++) {
        Result r = results.get(i);
        if (r.getType().equals(type) && r.getEmail().equals(email)) {
            result = r;
            exit = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code won't compile since is not implemeting setter-getter but implemeting it will work.

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look and try to implement and I'll come back to you

Comment: Why I have to do this `Value value = result.get(key);` How should be the constructor for the Value class?

Comment: Plus I need to have an ArrayList in the end, so I can use my Adapter properly, your answer is not grouping it at all

Comment: Wich type of ArrayList you need? Can be a new object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192534/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-bastida).

Comment: Please avoid doing a poster's entire work for them, especially when the assignment is supposed to be educational.

Answer (score 2):

Given your data class looks like this:

```
data class UserData(
        val exercise: String,
        val type: String,
        val emailAddress: String,
        val passed: Boolean
)
```

You could first group by `type` and `emailAddress` using a `Pair` as key for the resulting map:

```
val groupingMap = l.groupBy{ it.type to it.emailAddress }
```

`groupingMap` will be of type: `Map<Pair<String, String>, List<UserData>>`

After that you can iterate over that map using `forEach` like this:

```
resultMap.forEach { (groupKey, list) ->
    val numElements = list.count()
    val numTrueElements = list.count { it.passed }
    val (type, emailAddress) = groupKey
    println("$type, $emailAddress, $numTrueElements/$numElements")
}
```

Result:

> hand, Hans@gmail.com, 1/4
>   hand, Thiago@gmail.com, 2/2

<sub>There might be better suited types for `type` and maybe even `exercise` (it depends on the use-case) but for the sake of the example I chose `String`.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I think that You can use list> for grouping list of Objects to another list of Objects.